# V8 version in node and ChromeDevTools?

Tags: eclipse, node.js, v8, google-chrome-devtools

My main questions are:

1. What version of V8 am I running from node 0.4.10?
2. How can I tell if this version is compatible with ChromeDevTools 0.2.2 in Eclipse?

Background: I've almost got [Eclipse working for debugging node.js remotely](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/using-eclipse-as-node-applications-debugger).  In fact  it works perfectly (after adding a server proxy) for a simple "Hello World" app, but it won't hook up properly when I add "express" to the mix.  The Eclipse error is:

> An internal error occurred during: "Debug session initialization:
>   Remote NodeJS". Exception occured in callback

...which I tracked down to line 61 of the [this source code](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/source/browse/trunk/plugins/org.chromium.sdk/src/org/chromium/sdk/CallbackSemaphore.java?spec=svn646&r=643) (Thanks to the misspelling of "occured".)

I'd like to eliminate version skew possibilities before going further.

EDIT: Dug the stack trace out of the error log.  Hmmm, maybe I have an encoding problem in my server proxy?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception occured in callback
at org.chromium.sdk.CallbackSemaphore.tryAcquire(CallbackSemaphore.java:61)
at org.chromium.sdk.CallbackSemaphore.tryAcquireDefault(CallbackSemaphore.java:29)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.JavascriptVmImpl.getScripts(JavascriptVmImpl.java:33)
at org.chromium.debug.core.model.VProjectWorkspaceBridge.reloadScriptsAtStart(VProjectWorkspaceBridge.java:121)
at org.chromium.debug.core.model.LaunchInitializationProcedure.execute(LaunchInitializationProcedure.java:80)
at org.chromium.debug.core.model.LaunchInitializationProcedure.access$0(LaunchInitializationProcedure.java:64)
at org.chromium.debug.core.model.LaunchInitializationProcedure$1.run(LaunchInitializationProcedure.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Exception saved from callback
at org.chromium.sdk.CallbackSemaphore.callbackDone(CallbackSemaphore.java:72)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.DebugSession$ScriptLoader$2.callbackDone(DebugSession.java:276)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.BaseCommandProcessor.callThemBack(BaseCommandProcessor.java:136)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.BaseCommandProcessor.processIncoming(BaseCommandProcessor.java:103)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.V8CommandProcessor.processIncomingJson(V8CommandProcessor.java:109)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.StandaloneVmImpl$4.messageReceived(StandaloneVmImpl.java:108)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection$RegularMessageItem.report(SocketConnection.java:120)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.transport.SocketConnection$ResponseDispatcherThread.run(SocketConnection.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: < is an invalid character in resource name '<eval #83>.chromium'.
at org.chromium.debug.core.util.ChromiumDebugPluginUtil$4.tryCreate(ChromiumDebugPluginUtil.java:247)
at org.chromium.debug.core.util.ChromiumDebugPluginUtil$4.tryCreate(ChromiumDebugPluginUtil.java:1)
at org.chromium.debug.core.util.UniqueKeyGenerator.createUniqueKey(UniqueKeyGenerator.java:22)
at org.chromium.debug.core.util.ChromiumDebugPluginUtil.createFile(ChromiumDebugPluginUtil.java:254)
at org.chromium.debug.core.model.ResourceManager.createAndRegisterResourceFile(ResourceManager.java:106)
at org.chromium.debug.core.model.ResourceManager.addScript(ResourceManager.java:72)
at org.chromium.debug.core.model.VProjectWorkspaceBridge$2.success(VProjectWorkspaceBridge.java:131)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.DebugSession$ScriptLoader$1$1.call(DebugSession.java:236)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.DebugSession$ScriptLoader$1.processCall(DebugSession.java:258)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.DebugSession$ScriptLoader$1.success(DebugSession.java:233)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.V8Helper$2.success(V8Helper.java:120)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.V8CommandCallbackBase.messageReceived(V8CommandCallbackBase.java:25)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.V8CommandCallbackBase.messageReceived(V8CommandCallbackBase.java:1)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.BaseCommandProcessor$2.call(BaseCommandProcessor.java:99)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.BaseCommandProcessor$2.call(BaseCommandProcessor.java:1)
at org.chromium.sdk.internal.tools.v8.BaseCommandProcessor.callThemBack(BaseCommandProcessor.java:129)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: < is an invalid character in resource name '<eval #83>.chromium'.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkValidPath(Resource.java:432)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.create(File.java:116)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.create(File.java:196)
at org.chromium.debug.core.util.ChromiumDebugPluginUtil$4.tryCreate(ChromiumDebugPluginUtil.java:245)
... 20 more
```

Comment: 0.3.0 is released now. Hope it is fixed. Please let us know if it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process.versions` in the repl reveals this information:

```
> process.versions
{ node: '0.4.10', v8: '3.1.8.26', ares: '1.7.4', ev: '4.4', openssl: '1.0.0d' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  By any chance do you know what the version relationship/dependency between V8 and ChromeDevTools is?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any version-related problem here, at least at initialization stage.
V8 debug protocol is evolving quite slowly.

Unfortunately the message you cite is too general. Do you think you can find a stacktrace somewhere? The message may have 'details' button (but you would probably spot it), also the exception is usually logged. You can try to open a view "General->Error Log" (available in most Eclipse configurations), or you can take a look inside a file in your Eclipse workspace: /.metadata/.log.
The code indicates that there is a cause exception, which is missing from the error message.

Thank you for the spelling error report. :)

Comment: Added stack trace which I got from "Window->Show View->Error Log".  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: BTW it sounds like you're a developer of the Eclipse <-> ChromeDevTools connection.  Is there a proper place for bug reporting of such issues?  If not please drop me an email at john.mjhm@gmail.com if you'd like more info on the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see. It's a known problem under Windows http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=45

Unfortunately release 0.3.0 is not ready yet, but hopefully it will come out soon.

This should answer your question about a proper place :) You also can reach me in a discussion group (you have to subscribe) http://groups.google.com/group/chromedevtools-dev

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I look forward to 0.3.0.  Once this fix is in place I'll have a great workflow for remote debugging.